# How to detect end of data binding of Kendo Grid angular2?

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

We have an angular2 webapp where we are using Kendo Grid to display data. We retrieve the data from a restful webservice using JSDO. We need to be able to detect when the rows have been rendered. The reason being that we need to select the first row by default and display some extra data in fields outside the grid.

The Original Kendo Grid had the dataBound event that we could subscribe to. We have not been able to find an equivalent in Angular2 grid.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you bind to the Grid using `[(ngModel)]="mydata"` , the "databound" event is the moment you update `mydata`.

Let's say you subscribe to an Observable which gives you the result of your webservice.

You'll do something like that:

```
    myObservable.subscribe(
        val => {
            this.mydata = val;
            // Do whatever you need to do here
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        },
        () => {
        }
    );
```